# Android Custom layout for Notification - Issue with Image & text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I am trying to build a custom layout for notification but facing layout issues. The image is showing in center rather left side and text are not visible. Tried Liner layout, Text styles and color etc but no luck. What is missing in the layout ?

> Custome_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        style="Custom Notification Title" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        style="Custom Notification Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Java code

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String msg, String type, String imageURl, String fullid, String alert_price, int count) {
        WakeLocker.acquire(this);
        //msg = msg+"Amit this is testing for long text";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //count = count+5;
        System.out.println(msg);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.logo);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Amit notification");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, msg);
        mBuilder.setContent(contentView);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.sound);
        mNotificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);
        //RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,     uri);
        Ringtone ring = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        ring.play();
        ((Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService( Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(1600);

        WakeLocker.release();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this.**

You might have problem in defining `@id` instead Use `@+id`.

**Just replace below code in your XML.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**And it's Done.**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Layout is still same as shown in screen shot. Image is coming in the middle and title & text not showing at all.

Comment: @Amit I have checked that layout is working as u expected the image is at left and both text views are showing text properly. Please replace my code  in your xml.

Comment: Jay, i copied ur xml as is and tried it many times with different android version and models but its not working for me... Did you also used my java code , thinking there could be issue with java code..

Comment: @Amit Then what's wrong with my answer their what i have suggested it's working. It's issue with your image size. So for that also i have give `ic_launcher` in my answer. Please accept answer if it is useful to you. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the size of logo image I was using. With a smaller image of 75x75 it worked as expected with my layout code.
Its a mistake so I am not selecting this as an answer but it might be useful for people in future...